# I cannot delete the user in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot delete the user I created in mysql. I am getting an error like this. What could be the reason?

> Drop failed for Login 'fırat'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: maybe the user had an open connection?

Comment: you say mysql in your question, but say sql server/mssql in your title and tags.

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for rules. These include: `A login cannot be dropped while it is logged in. A login that owns any securable, server-level object, or SQL Server Agent job cannot be dropped.`